# What would be your reply if someone asks you, "How do you do?"

Tags: british-english, formality, politeness

What would be your reply, if someone asks you

- How do you do?

Comment: The form is, in fairness, much less used than it used to be. It was the standard way of responding to a formal introduction to someone. Both would say 'How do you do?' to one another, neither expecting an answer. Unfortunate souls who had been brought up outside of metropolitan etiquette might answer 'nicely thankyou' and thus confirm their serving status. Watch Downton Abbey.

Comment: Considering the preference many have for prioritising functional analysis over formal, actually calling 'How do you do?' a question might be contentious. As Erik says, it's purely phatic, unlike 'How are you?' which is solicitous of a logical response. In fact, the shortened form 'Howdy' has lost the question mark.

Comment: I read _How do you do_ (not asking)  is the correct reply. It seems Kate Middleton (Prince William's wife) said to the Queen "Nice to meet you" instead of "How do you do?". I guess if one met the Queen and told her "How do you do?", "How do you do" would be her answer.

Answer (score 2):

In British English, the standard response to ‘How do you do?’ is ‘How do you do?’
which is not used these days.

It is common for Americans to say, ‘Fine, thank you’ in response to ‘How do you do?’

You can chose that.

Comment: Have you checked the 'possible duplicate' post?

Comment: Is it really common?  I've never actually heard anyone say "How do you do?" outside of fiction before.

Comment: I haven't used it either. I remembered to have read it long time back. But the link checked after your comment was thorough on this and explained that it was used but not anymore.

Comment: _which is not used these days._ It's still used in the UK and by English abroad quite a lot, especially in formal settings. If one is are being introduced to someone one would probably say _how do you do_ as you shake hands, and they could respond with _how do you do_, _pleased to meet you_, or other such pleasantries.

Answer (score 0):

I would repeat the question back to them without actually answering it or expecting them to answer my question. It's a purely phatic formulation.